# fault string: No such parameter param defined for the operation, please check the WSDL for the service

Tags: apex

I am facing issue on click of a Javascript Button.
Getting the below error
fault string:

> No such parameter param defined for the operation, please check the
>   WSDL for the service

Below is the code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")} 

var callout = "" + sforce.apex.execute(
    "AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl",
    "exportToExcel",
    {param:"{!Object_Analysis__c.Id}"}); 

if (callout == 'OK') { 
    alert("Your Request is Successful. Click OK and please wait while the page refreshes"); 
    window.location.reload(); 
} 
else { 
    alert("Request Failed " + callout ); 
}
```

---

```
global class AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl {

  public AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl(){

  }
    public static void exportMultipleToExcel(List selectedIDs){
        List objAnalysisList = new List();
        objAnalysisList =  [select name,Field_Count__c,Filter__c,Object_Label__c,Object_Name__c,Record_Count__c,Record_Types_Count__c,
                        (select name,Label__c,Populated_On__c,Populated_On_per__c,Type__c from Field_Analysis__r order by Populated_On__c DESC ) 
                            from Object_Analysis__c where id IN :selectedIDs ]; 
        string excelXML = prepareHeaderAndStyles();
        for(Object_Analysis__c obj : objAnalysisList){
            excelXML += prepareWorkSheet(obj);
        }
        excelXML += '';  
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attach.setFileName('MultipleObjectAnalysis.xls');
        attach.setInline(false);
        attach.setBody(Blob.valueof(excelXML));

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setUseSignature(false);

        User u = [select email from user where id=:userinfo.getUserId()];
      mail.setToAddresses(new List{u.email});
        mail.setSubject('Object Analysis : Multiple Record Analysis Export');
        string mailBody = ' Hi,  Your Request for Multiple Object Analysis export to Excel file is completed. please find the attachment.  ';
        mailBody += 'Regards, 
 Object Analysis';
        mail.setHtmlBody(mailBody);
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attach }); 

        // Send the email
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

        /*Blob bv = Blob.valueof(excelXML);
        Attachment d = new Attachment(); 
        d.name = 'MultipleObjectAnalysis.xls';
        d.ContentType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        d.Body = bv;
        d.ParentId = objAnalysisList[0].id;
        insert d;*/

    }
  WebService static String exportToExcel(String objAnlyID) {

  if(String.isNotBlank(objAnlyID)) {
      try{
            Object_Analysis__c objAny = [select name,Field_Count__c,Filter__c,Object_Label__c,Object_Name__c,Record_Count__c,Record_Types_Count__c,
                                   (select name,Label__c,Populated_On__c,Populated_On_per__c,Type__c from Field_Analysis__r order by Populated_On__c DESC ) from Object_Analysis__c where id =:objAnlyID ]; 
        string filter  = (!string.isBlank(objAny.Filter__c)) ? objAny.Filter__c : ''; 
            string s = prepareHeaderAndStyles();
                s += prepareWorkSheet(objAny);
        s += ''; 

        Blob bv = Blob.valueof(s);
        Attachment d = new Attachment(); 
        d.name = objAny.name + '.xls';
        d.ContentType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        d.Body = bv;
        d.ParentId = objAny.id;
        insert d;

            return 'OK';    
          }catch (Exception e) {
                return 'ERROR Message:' + e.getMessage();
          }
        }else {
            return 'ERROR Message: Object Analysis record ID is not specified ';
        }
    }
    public static string prepareWorkSheet(Object_Analysis__c objAny){
        string filter  = (!string.isBlank(objAny.Filter__c)) ? objAny.Filter__c : ''; 
        string s = '';
           s += '';
          //Object Analysis details
          s += 'Object Analysis : ' + objAny.name   + '  ';
          s += 'Object Analysis Name   ' + objAny.name  + ' ';
            s += 'Object Label   ' + objAny.Object_Label__c  + ' ';
          s += 'Object Name   ' + objAny.Object_Name__c  + ' ';
          s += 'Field Count  ' + objAny.Field_Count__c  + '';
            s += 'Row Count  ' + objAny.Record_Count__c  + '';
            s += 'Filter   ' + filter  + ' ';
            s += 'Field Analysis ';
            // header row START ==================>
          s += 'Field Label';
          s += 'Field Name';
          s += 'Field Type';
          s += 'Populated On';
          s += 'Populated On %';
          s += '';
          // header row END ==================>
          // DATA ROWS
          for(Field_Analysis__c fieldAny : objAny.Field_Analysis__r){
            s += '' + fieldAny.Label__c + '';
            s += '' + fieldAny.Name  + '';
            s += '' + fieldAny.Type__c  + '';
            s += '' + fieldAny.Populated_On__c  + '';
          s += '' + fieldAny.Populated_On_per__c + '';
          }
        s += '';
        s += '';
            s += '';
            //s += '';
            s += 'False';
            s += 'False';
            s += '';
        s += '';
        return s;
    }
    public static string prepareHeaderAndStyles(){
        string s = '';
            s += '';
            s += '';
          s += '';
            s += '';       
            s += '';
            s += '';
            s += '';
            s += '';
            s += '';
            s += '';      
            s += '';
            s += '';
            s += '';      
            s += '';
            s += '';
            s += '';
            s += '';      
            s += '';
            s += '';
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also post code for "AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl"?

Comment: Hi Shailesh,
I have added the controller -- AnalyzeObjectExportCtrl

Answer (score 1):

Please add,

```
var Object_Analysis = sforce.sObject("Object_Analysis__c");
```

after

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}
```

The error you are having is because the parameter you are passing should be "objAnlyID" and not "param". So change it to :

```
"exportToExcel",
    {objAnlyID:"{!Object_Analysis.Id}"});
```

where Object_Analysis is the variable we got from the first line.

Please refer this for more info:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_and_ajax.htm

Comment: Hi Shailesh,
Thank you for the response
I am facing a diffrenent issue now.

It says Sforce is not a function

Please help

Comment: Please try changing the versions of the libraries that you have added:
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")}